# Ошибка при получении данных с массива PHP

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

пытаюсь достать данные с db при помощи PDO но получаю ошибку:

```
Notice: Undefined index: product_id in /sites/site.com/brain_import/index.php on line 22
```

Вот мой код:

```
$data = $db2->row("SELECT * FROM oc_product WHERE product_id = :product_id", $params);
var_dump ($data);
echo $data['product_id'];
```

Вот var_dump:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(31) { ["product_id"]=> string(2) "34" ["model"]=> string(9) "Product 7" ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["upc"]=> string(0) "" ["ean"]=> string(0) "" ["jan"]=> string(0) "" ["isbn"]=> string(0) "" ["mpn"]=> string(0) "" ["location"]=> string(0) "" ["quantity"]=> string(4) "1000" ["stock_status_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["image"]=> string(31) "catalog/demo/ipod_shuffle_1.jpg" ["manufacturer_id"]=> string(1) "8" ["shipping"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(8) "100.0000" ["points"]=> string(1) "0" ["tax_class_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["date_available"]=> string(10) "2009-02-03" ["weight"]=> string(10) "5.00000000" ["weight_class_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["length"]=> string(10) "0.00000000" ["width"]=> string(10) "0.00000000" ["height"]=> string(10) "0.00000000" ["length_class_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["subtract"]=> string(1) "1" ["minimum"]=> string(1) "1" ["sort_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" ["viewed"]=> string(1) "0" ["date_added"]=> string(19) "2009-02-03 18:07:54" ["date_modified"]=> string(19) "2011-09-30 01:07:17" } }
```

Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело не в PDO, а в кривой обертке над ним.

Метод, который называется row() должен возвращать одномерный массив, а по какой-то неведомой причине возвращает двумерный

Вот [нормальная обертка](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#run), с ее помощью все делается так же удобно, но без таких косяков

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oc_product WHERE product_id = :product_id";
$data = $db->run($sql, $params)->fetch();
var_dump ($data);
echo $data['product_id'];
```

Comment: public function query($sql, $params = []){
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    if (!empty($params)){
      foreach ($params as $key => $val){
        $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $val);
      }
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
  }

  public function row($sql, $params = []){
    $result = $this->query($sql, $params);
    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

  public function column($sql, $params = []){
    $result = $this->query($sql, $params);
    return $result->fetchColumn();
  }

Comment: И так понял ошибка в return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); то все ок